# motion planning without orientation constrains?

Tags: robotic-arm, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I was wondering if you could ask for motion planning without specifying orientation constraints for the end effector.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60815/motion-planning-without-orientation-constrains?/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know which version you are using (arm navigation or moveit).
But you could just add some orientation constraints and set the tolerance really high. In that way it doesn't matter also.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1